# Incompatible Titanium Modules

Tags: titanium, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

Third party modules build for 6.0.0.GA are not incompatible with 7.0.0.GA.
When rebuilding for 7.0.0.GA I am getting bellow error.

```
 /Users/dipannita/Documents/Projects/Modules_For_7/Ti-Android-SMSVerification/android/build.xml:55: Cannot find /Users/dipannita/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/7.0.0.GA/module/android/build.xml imported from /Users/dipannita/Documents/Projects/Modules_For_7/Ti-Android-SMSVerification/android/build.xml
```

How to rebuild modules for 7.0.0.GA using ant?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at this documentation on how to build modules:
http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Android_Module_Upgrade_Guide

And use `appc ti build -p android -b` instead of the old `ant`